# Azure Application gateway : HostName Mystery

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Suppose I have a VM with following property

```
FQDN :trialinstance.westus.cloudapp.azure.com
Public IP : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Private IP  : YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
```

as it is an linux VM, output of 'hostname -f' command is

```
trialinstance.somerandomguid.dx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

now I need some help in understanding these :

```
what will be the value for Target field in BackendPool ?
What will be the hostname ?
How setting 127.0.0.1 works as hostname ??
```

Azure documentation and explanation is very very inadequate :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what will be the value for Target field in BackendPool ?

If your Linux VM and application gateway are in a same Vnet, you could use your VM's private IP.

[image]

If your VM and application gateway are not in a VNet, you should use VM's public IP or FQDN `trialinstance.westus.cloudapp.azure.com`.

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-gateway-portal#add-servers-to-backend-pools).

> What will be the hostname ?

You should know how heath probe works,  custom probe is indeed not used for any DNS name resolution or for any network routing. Instead, the probe "knows" which backend server pool to hit through the custom probe’s association with specific Backend HTTP Settings, which are in turn associated with one or many Backend Pools through one or many Routing Rules.

If multi-site is not configure, you could set it `127.0.0.1`. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview#custom-health-probe).

Comment: You also could check comments in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-probe-portal).

Comment: why 127.0.0.1 why not public ip as host ?? how come it will ping 127.0.0.1 when it is not installed on the machine. I am confused

Comment: No, Azure will not ping the host, it will probe backend pool vm's private ip/public ip.

Comment: See this question. `Could you clarify the value of the `Host` when I'm using Application Gateway in front of multiple Service Fabric environments that are configured for different public DNS? example: sf1.mydomain.com, sf2.mydomain.com, etc. Should use these values for the `Host` in custom probes?`  .

Comment: ` Hostname would not work in this scenario, similar to web apps.  The problem is we preserve the host name.  If you used those values as they are different you would get unhealthy hosts because sf2.mydomain.com would not resolve for a probe to sf1.mydomain.com.  This in on the backlog of items and is being worked on.`

Comment: I am trying this for single host single entrypoint setup and still probes  are not working and logs are of no help either

Comment: Do you configure VM's public IP or VM's nic? The probe log?

Comment: yes public IP is configured / what is a probe log ?? only log I can see is application gateway logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163765/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-blindsniper).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log  See this link